# How do I mark only one selection as TRUE in a dynamic zenity radiolist?

Tags: bash, awk, zenity

This is the code I have at the moment - it finds all files that have the file extension `.sv` and lists them in a `zenity` radiolist, however, none of the items are selected. Of course, if I change `awk '{print "FALSE\n"$0}'` to `awk '{print "TRUE\n"$0}'` they'll all be selected, which I don't want.

```
test_name=$(
    find ../tests/ -name '*.sv' | 
    awk '{print "FALSE\n"$0}' |
    cut -d "/" -f3 | 
    cut -d "." -f1 |
    zenity  --list \
            --radiolist \
            --title "Select test" \
            --text "Tests..." \
            --column "Box" \
            --column "Files"
) #select test via zenity
```

How do I make just the first item be selected, and the rest not? I know this can be done by using arrays, as suggested by [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21236333/set-the-default-selection-on-a-specific-line-in-zenity-list) question/answer, however it would require significantly more code. Is there a more elegant way of achieving this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can amend your `awk` command to print "TRUE" if it is the first line to be processed. You can also remove your `cut` commands by using `basename`:

```
test_name=$(
    find ../tests/ -name '*.sv' -exec basename {} .sv \; | 
    awk 'NR==1{print "TRUE\n"$0} NR>1{print "FALSE\n"$0}' |
    zenity  --list \
            --radiolist \
            --title "Select test" \
            --text "Tests..." \
            --column "Box" \
            --column "Files"
) #select test via zenity
```

You could also use `sed` in place of `awk`:

```
sed -e '1iTRUE' -e '1!iFALSE'
```